# 1 second delay after ping command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to linux scripting so apologies if this is a trivial question.
I have written the following script.
The script basically pings the ip addresses in 192.168.11.0 once and prints if the response has been successful or not.

```
#!/bin/bash

NETWORK=192.168.11
IP_START=101
IP_END=148

IP_COUNTER=$IP_START

while [[ $IP_COUNTER -le $IP_END ]]
   do
       ip=$NETWORK.$IP_COUNTER
       ping -c1 $ip &>/dev/null && echo "$ip is UP" || echo "$ip is DOWN"
       IP_COUNTER=$(($IP_COUNTER +1))
   done
```

However I would like to have a 1-second delay between the ping and the "echo "$ip is UP"..." part. I am not sure how to do this. 
I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sleep.

`if ping -c1 $ip &>/dev/null ; then
  sleep 1
  echo $ip is up
else
  sleep 1
  echo $ip is down
fi`

As I look at your code, maybe better matching your coding style will be

`ping -c1 $ip &>/dev/null && sleep 1 && echo "$ip is up" || sleep 1 && echo "$ip is down"`

"True" posix sleep will accept only integral values (sleep 1, sleep 2), but linux version of sleep can also handle non-integral (sleep 0.25 for 1/4 of second).

Comment: Oh yea I see. that makes sense. thanks for the quick response. Appreciate the help. It seems that when the ip is not reachable the echo takes a bit longer to print on screen. Do you see any reason why this could happen?

Comment: Yes, the units are seconds, as says note on end of my answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry I noticed it later. Would you know why i would take longer to respond to the unreachable IP addresses?

Comment: When remote host is reachable, then ping reply comes almost immediately (tens of miliseconds), but when the host is not reachable, ping must wait some time, if reply arrive. This timeout in seconds can be set using -W param (so for one second waiting for reply you will use `ping -c1 -W1`)